# Ошибка "[22-Nov-2019 13:28:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/thedbfky/beta_html/actions/test.php on line 4"

Tags: php

После каждого запуска скрипта вылетает ошибка:
[Время + Дата] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in *Путь* on line 4

Если честно, то я пытался устранить, но мои муки были безуспешны.
Наверно ,потому что я нуб в php.

Мой код:

```
<?php
$names_array = array("Олег"=>[0],"Артём"=>[1],"Кира"=>[2],"Лера"=>[3],"Денис"=>[4],"Иван"=>[5],"Катя"=>[6]);
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $nowname = $names_array[$i];
    if ($_POST['yourname'] == $nowname){
        echo 'Alert!';
    }
}
?>
```

Данный скрипт должен выводить текст если в $_POST['yourname'] находится например 'Денис'.

Comment: У вас в массиве нет ключа 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$names_array = array("Олег","Артём","Кира","Лера","Денис","Иван","Катя");
```

а если все же нужен ассациотивный массив, то используйте специальный цикл для них.